# command to list all the folders and sub-folders in a directory in linux

Tags: linux, unix, command

I would like to check all the folders and sub-folders in a directory.

`ls -R` works fine, but it lists all the files in each folder and sub-folder. As a result I can't see what I want to check unless `ls -R |less`.

`ls -R | less` is also not a good choice because I have thousands and thousands of files in each sub-folder.

Comment: Use find with some filtering?

Comment: Your question title contradicts your intentions.

Comment: The wording of the question is a bit confusing, but if you're looking for a way to get the list of directories and sub-directories use "find -type d". If that's not what you're looking for, please edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Install `tree` package. You can easily change max display depth of directory with `-L`.

For example:

```
$ tree -L 1 /
/
├── bin -> usr/bin
├── boot
├── dev
├── etc
├── home
├── lib -> usr/lib
├── lib64 -> usr/lib
├── lost+found
├── media
├── mnt
├── opt
├── proc
├── root
├── run
├── sbin -> usr/bin
├── srv
├── sys
├── tmp
├── usr
└── var
```